# PHP: Sort an array in order of letters in another array

Tags: php, sorting

I'm making a little hangman game, and I want to sort the guesses the person makes in order of the actual word; Here is my code:

```
$word = "peach";
$_SESSION['letters'] = str_split($word);
```

ˆThat is where I make the word into an array, and I want when correct letters are added to an array, that they be sorted in order of the word. Is there any way I could do this, or another way I could write it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Can you give an example of what you would like?

Comment: @Mike So if I had the guesses a, c, and h, then I would want it to echo out as blank, blank, a, c, h (without commas) if the word was peach.

Comment: I meant to put the first 3 letters in a separate order, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood. Try this:

```
<?php
$guess = 'reach';
$guess_array = str_split($guess);
$word = 'peach';
$word_array = str_split($word);

$result = '';
foreach($word_array as $letter)
{
    if(in_array($letter, $guess_array))
    {
        $result .= $letter;
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= '_';
    }
}
echo($result);
// outputs: "_each"
?>
```

Comment: I don't want it sorted alphabetically, I'd like to have it sorted in the order of the word

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably going about it wrong. You don't need to sort the array. Just set an array with the letters in the word and another array with the guesses. Then loop over the array with the word and see if the respective value is found in the guesses array. Something like this:

```
$word = "rumplestiltskin";    
$letters = str_split($word);

// Assume the user gets at least 6 guesses:
$guesses = array('r', 's', 't', 'l', 'n', 'e');

// Display the letters guessed correctly
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
    // Set both to lower case just in case
    if (in_array(strtolower($letter), array_map('strtolower', $guesses)) === true) {
        echo " $letter ";
    }
    else {
        echo " _ ";
    }
}

// Produces: r _ _ _ l e s t _ l t s _ _ n
```